# В чем отличие двух методов слияния веток (git merge)?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

Вопрос по git.
У меня есть две ветки. Одна называется master, другая feature.

Интересует вопрос. **В чем будет отличие двух методов слияния?**
Первый метод.

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git merge feature`

Второй метод.

1. `git checkout feature`
2. `git merge master`

Comment: В том в какую ветку попадёт результат. Код будет одинаковый

Answer (score 2):

отличие состоит в том, какой из указателей («ветка» в программе *git* — это указатель на коммит) передвинется, а какой останется на месте.

передвинется тот указатель, который в момент выполнения команды *merge* был текущим.

---

командой

```
git checkout ветка1
```

вы делаете текущим указатель `ветка1`.

а последующей командой

```
git merge ветка2
```

вы переставляете текущий указатель (`ветка1`):

- либо на вновь сформированный «коммит слияния», в случае, если между коммитами, на которые указывают `ветка1` и `ветка2` была «развилка» (см. ниже)
- либо на самый «свежий» из двух коммитов, на которые указывали `ветка1` и `ветка2`, если между этими коммитами «развилки» не было

а указатель `ветка2` останется на том же месте, где и был.

---

иллюстрация.

1. нет «развилки»:

   ```
   а - б - в - г
   (ветка1 указывает на коммит «б», а ветка2 указывает на коммит «г» (или наоборот))
   ```

   после команды *merge* `ветка1` будет указывать на самый «свежий» из этих двух коммитов («г»), а указатель `ветка2` останется там, где и был
2. есть «развилка»:

   ```
   а - б - в - г
        \
         д -е 
   (ветка1 указывает на коммит «г», а ветка2 указывает на коммит «е» (или наоборот))
   ```

   после команды *merge* будет выглядеть так:

   ```
   а - б - в - г
        \       \
         д - е - ж
   («ж» — коммит слияния, сформированный командой merge)
   ```

   и `ветка1` будет указывать на коммит «ж», а указатель `ветка2` останется там, где и был.

Answer (score 1):

В таком простом случае на уровне кода различий нет.

Однако ветка `master` обычно используется как "главная", релизная, в которую добавляют доработки из `feature`.

`master => feature` часто используется, когда нужно добавить какие-то изменения (например, появление новых классов) из мастер-ветки в ту, где идет разработка, чтобы иметь возможность их задействовать. Такое регулярное "подливание" удобно, когда, наконец, будет слияние `feature => master`, потому как будут минимальные различия, и меньше придется разруливать конфликты.

Тут на SO есть описание по этому процессу: [git flow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-flow/info)

> То есть при выделенное ветке master при слиянии с feature в основную ветку попадут коммиты из master и затрут коммиты feature?

Нет, коммиты в принципе затереть нельзя. Даже если сильно напортачить, можно сделать `git reflog`, это журнал, и по хешам коммитов "собрать" то, что вам нужно.

Гит работает на уровне строк. Он сливает файлы построчно, ища различия. Если в одной ветке изменились одни строки, а в другом - другие, он просто сольет и [те и другие изменения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/git-merge/info). Но если поменялись одни и те же строки, будет конфликт слияния, который тут же можно исправить: принять один из вариантов.

`git - the stupid content tracker` (из `man git`).

Я думаю, вам нужно прочитать подробнее как работает гит.

> При текущей выбранной ветке feature при слиянии с веткой мастер коммиты из feature попадут в ветку master. При таких двух разных методах слияния какая ветка станет основной(выбранной)?

Ветка `master` - на уровне договоренности считается "основной". Это релизная, публичная ветка. А "выбранная", это та, на которой стоит указатель. Это то, что показывается в рабочем каталоге.

Comment: Уточнение. Чем будет отличаться результат? То есть при выделенное ветке master при слиянии с feature в основную ветку попадут коммиты из master и затрут коммиты feature? При текущей выбранной ветке feature при слиянии с веткой мастер коммиты из feature попадут в ветку master. 
При таких двух разных методах слияния какая ветка станет основной(выбранной)?